# Product of Two Orthogonal Operators

Tags: linear-algebra

The question I am asking is: Show that the product of two orthogonal operators $S$ and $T$ on inner product space $V$ is also Orthogonal.

Knowing that the inner product space $\left \| T(x) \right \|=\left \| x \right \|$ for all $x\in V$.

As well as $TT^{*}=T^{*}T=I$ where $I$ is the identity and $T^{*}$ is the adjoint of $T$.

Comment: Just use the definition.

Comment: Which definition are you talking about?

Comment: Definition of an orthogonal operator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An orthogonal operator preserves the inner product, i.e., if $T$ is orthogonal, then $\left<u, v\right> = \left<Tu, Tv\right>$ for all $u, v$.  We need to show that if $T$ and $S$ are both orthogonal, then $TS$ is also orthogonal.  We have, for all $u, v$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left<TSu, TSv\right> &=& \left<T(Su), T(Sv)\right> \\ 
&=&\left<Su, Sv\right>\quad\text{since T is orthogonal}\\
&=&\left<u, v\right> \quad \quad\text{since S is orthogonal}
\end{eqnarray*}
This calculation shows that $\left<TSu, TSv\right> = \left<u, v\right>$ for all $u, v$, which implies that $TS$ is orthogonal.